# How do I install node-usb on raspberry pi?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, usb, node-red, node-gyp

I'm running a raspberry pi with Debian. I'm attempting to make a node-red node. I have been successful thus far, but now it stopped working the last time I tried to reinstall it and I'm not sure why. First I try to link my node using:

```
sudo npm link
```

I run this in the file with the file with the `package.json` file.

It seems to run fine until it attempts to "install" [usb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb) (A fork of `node-usb`, which worked fine previously), after which I get the following stacktrace:

```
> usb@1.2.0 install /home/pi/Documents/Nodes/ant_plus_node/node_modules/usb
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://github.com/tessel/node-usb/releases/download/1.2.0/usb_bindings-v1.2.0-node-v48-linux-arm.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for usb@1.2.0 and node@6.11.2 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/6.11.2"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/home/pi/Documents/Nodes/ant_plus_node/node_modules/usb/.node-gyp"
make ✖ ERR  Missing Makefile / Bakefile
make ℹ info Run "make init" to generate a Makefile.
ant_plus_node@0.2.2 /home/pi/Documents/Nodes/ant_plus_node
```

Now when I try to use the node I get the following error in node-red:

```
"Error: Cannot find module '/home/pi/Documents/Nodes/ant_plus_node/node_modules/usb/src/binding/usb_bindings.node'"
```

I have attempted to run `make init` in `/home/pi/Documents/Nodes/ant_plus_node/node_modules/usb/`:

```
make ℹ info Running default template in  /home/pi/Documents/Nodes/ant_plus_node/node_modules/usb
make ⚠ warn .npmignore    already exists, skipping
make ⚠ warn package.json  already exists, merging
make ℹ info .npmignore    -> ./.npmignore
make ℹ info package.json  -> ./package.json
make ℹ info .eslintignore -> ./.eslintignore
make ℹ info Makefile      -> ./Makefile
make ℹ info Build success in 263ms
```

, and doing another `sudo npm link`, but I still get the same stack-trace. Does anyone have a potential solution to the problem? I have checked the github releases, and unforunately there is no `usb_bindings.node` file suited for my OS.

I have:
`nodejs` version `6.11.12`
`npm` version `3.10.10`
And as python is mentiond by `node-gyp`:
`python` version `2.7.9`
`python3` version `3.4.2`

Comment: What happens if you run without sudo

Comment: I get permission denied for making a `lib` folder in the `npm-global` folder. I followed [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) to change the global npm directory due to not having access to `/root/.node-gyp/6.11.2` as root. It however did not work. 
Using `--unsafe-perm` is also not really an option as I use a local npm package written in typescript which for some reason won't compile, and npm won't use the build folder of that package.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be running any of this as root (with or without sudo) if you can help it, and the installs should all be local not global if possible as it gets round nearly all the permissions problems

Comment: Hm I tried installing `node-gyp` locally (was still forced to use `sudo`), but that didn't really help. `node-gyp` seems to be the cause of all the problems here.